# many of the nltk package methods / tools are not working

Tags: python, nltk, nlp

1)I tried the code from the official book on nltk package named /Natural Language Processing' but it gives error

```
dt = nltk.DiscourseTester(['A student dances', 'Every student is a person'])
print(dt.readings())
```

I get the error

> NLTK was unable to find the mace4 file!
>   Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the PROVER9 environment variable.

2)I tried to use another code from the book:

```
from nltk import load_parser
parser = load_parser('drt.fcfg', logic_parser=nltk.DrtParser())
trees = parser.parse('Angus owns a dog'.split())
print(trees[0].node['sem'].simplify())
```

I got the error

> AttributeError: module 'nltk' has no attribute 'DrtParser'

3)I tried the below code:

```
    from nltk.sem import cooper_storage as cs
sentence = 'every girl chases a dog'
trees = cs.parse_with_bindops(sentence, grammar='storage.fcfg')
semrep = trees[0].label()
cs_semrep = cs.CooperStore(semrep)
print(cs_semrep.core)

for bo in cs_semrep.store:
    print(bo)
cs_semrep.s_retrieve(trace=True)
for reading in cs_semrep.readings:
    print(reading)
```

It worked but still it gave the below error:

> AttributeError: 'CooperStore' object has no attribute 'core'

4) I tried another code from book:

```
from nltk import load_parser
parser = load_parser('simple-sem.fcfg', trace=0)
sentence = 'Angus gives a bone to every dog'
tokens = sentence.split()
trees = parser.parse(tokens)
for tree in trees:
    print(tree.node['SEM'])
```

I got the below error:

> NotImplementedError: Use label() to access a node label.

Please let me know what to do? Are these features deprecated because I heard that many of the features of nltk are. Please suggest a way out for all those features mentioned.

Comment: Which Python and NLTK versions are you working with ?

Comment: Python 3.7 and NLTK 3.4

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, actually I was following the code from the book instead of NLTK's online version of book which is updated. So following the updated version solved the problems.